# SaveAs automatically turns on AutoSave in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large file that downloads prices on a daily basis and then saves a backup copy of the file under a new name with a date suffix attached. Want to save this only on the local drive and not have it automatically upload to Sharepoint. This is for two reasons (1) speed -- at times the network connection is slow and saving to Sharepoint degrades performance and (2) the "Uploading to Sharepoint" dialog seems to hang, even after the file has clearly been uploaded.

Even though I've turn autosave off, it seems to automatically come back on when the .SaveAs code runs. Is this because of the file format that has been chosen? I'm generally using .xlsb to reduce file size.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
Dim OrigName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim NewName As String
Dim DateSuffix As String

If ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = True Then
    ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
    Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = False
End If

SaveStart = Timer
Sheets("Parameters").Activate
RptDt = Range("End_Date").Offset(0, 1)
DateSuffix = Format(RptDt, "yyyymmdd") 'Year(RptDt) & Month(RptDt) & Day(RptDt)
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
OrigName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
OrigName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
NewName = OrigName & " " & DateSuffix
If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 4) = "xlsb" Then
    NewName = Path & "\" & NewName & ".xlsb"
    OrigName = Path & "\" & OrigName & ".xlsb"
Else
    NewName = Path & "\" & NewName & ".xlsm"
    OrigName = Path & "\" & OrigName & ".xlsm"
End If
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With ActiveWorkbook
    If Right(.Name, 4) = "xlsb" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs NewName, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        BeforeSave2 = Timer
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs OrigName, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs NewName, FileFormat:=52
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs OrigName, FileFormat:=52
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = True
Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
```

Comment: If you instead use SaveCopyAs that likely will not have the problem.  As long as you're saving the copy in the same file format should work fine.  And one less save.

Comment: Thanks, that did work with two caveats. First .SaveCopyAs doesn't need you to specify the file format -- I presume it automatically saves it in the same format as the original file. Second, I couldn't use the Path prefix in the file name (because that was picking up the sharepoint path, not the local path).

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Here's the revised code:

Comment: Please *update your question* when adding clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the revised code using SaveCopyAs:

```
NewName = NewName & ".xlsb"
OrigName = OrigName & ".xlsb"

With ActiveWorkbook
    If Right(.Name, 4) = "xlsb" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveCopyAs NewName
        .SaveCopyAs OrigName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveCopyAs NewName
        .SaveCopyAs OrigName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End With
```